# Не работают шаблонные строки

Tags: javascript

Пишу строку вида `"строка текста ${выражение} строка текста"`, и вместо например значения переменной в месте `${выражение}`, javaScript воспринимает это все как цельную строку, то есть выводя мне строку прямо так `"строка текста ${выражение} строка текста"`, как есть. То есть он не воспринимает знак $. Попробовал и в консоле в браузере и в js файле в IDE.

Подскажите в чем проблема или что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> что я делаю не так?

Шаблонные строки заключаются в обратные кавычки, а не в одинарные или двойные.

```js
let test = 'privet';

console.log(`Vsem ${test}`);
```

---

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

В доках это показано

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]